# How do I parse an unnamed nested json array in the Snowflake database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've found the [flatten function](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-flatten.html) but the example is simpler than my real example.  It can be created with the following code:

```
create or replace table test2 as
select '5dd17ef333de385a360e0ef1' as id,
parse_json('{
    "_id" : "5dd17ef333de385a360e0ef1",
    "uid" : "5dd175d3333b85961df27c51",
    "task_info" : {
        "reps=1" : [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "cached" : false,
                    "transform max RAM" : 51445000,
                }
            ], 
            [ 
                {
                    "cached" : false,
                    "transform max RAM" : 51445000,
                }
            ], 
            [ 
                {
                    "cached" : true,
                    "transform max RAM" : 51445000,
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}')::variant as json_rec
;
```

Then my attempt to parse it:

```
select id
, json_rec:_id::string(100) as extracted_id
, value:cached::string as cached
, value
, json_rec
  from
    test2
  , lateral flatten( input => json_rec:task_info )
;
```

The cached is clearly not going deep enough, although I am unclear of the syntax that is required to fish something like these values out.  Thoughts?

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Snowflake is the database

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is a separate row for each of the items in the innermost array (i.e. 3 rows for the above example), then you can use `recursive=>true` and filter on `key='cached'`, like this:

```
select id
, json_rec:_id::string(100) as extracted_id
, value as cached
, json_rec
  from
    test2
  , lateral flatten( input => json_rec:task_info, recursive=>true)
where key='cached';
```

Comment: my original comment contained an error on my part, solution works, thanks!

Comment: follow up - `select id
, json_rec:_id::string(100) as extracted_id
, case when key = 'cached' then value else null end as cached
, case when key = 'transform max RAM' then value else null end as transform_max_ram
, seq, key, path, index, value, this
  from
    test2
  , lateral flatten( input => json_rec:task_info, recursive=>true)
  where key in ('cached', 'transform max RAM')
  ;` how do i indicate the groups of these related values?  the only info i have appears to be the first part of the path - but that doesn't seem very elegant...

Comment: How do you want the output to look like? 3 rows with a column "cached" and one "transform_max_ram"?

Comment: ultimately i turned this into 3 rows for each record and 2 for each field, so 6 total.  i then pivot these to columns based on the reps=1... and did a distinct as my data doesn't appear to have a difference for these values.